# Large int in c++

Tags: c++

Suppose i want to store 2^100 in a variable. No integer type allows this. But this can be stored in a double variable with zeros after the decimal point i.e the following code may be used.

```
double no = 1;
int i = 1;
for(i=1;i<=100;i++) no*=2;
```

I now want to print 'no' without what is there after decimal point. Can this be done. I'm just interested in printing and not its storage.

Note: I know the problem can be done using array of integer,so please don't suggest that method.

Comment: You have C++ in the title but used C as tag. Which one you want to use? Those are very different languages even though C++ is mostly compatible to C.

Comment: @johannes Does it matter. It is c++.

Comment: What exactly are you interested in accomplishing here?

Comment: @Segmented I want to print 2^100 without using string or array.

Comment: The double will not store the exact value here, it can only hold so many significant digits.

Comment: Also, any power of two in binary is going to be a 1 followed by a number of zeros, so storing this huge power of two is pointless anyways...

Comment: @Segmented As long as we only deal with powers of 2 then the floating point representation is exact: One significant digit (1) and an exponent equal to 100.

Answer (score 4):

You are talking about arbitrary precision integers for which I would advice to use a library such as GMP. See https://gmplib.org.

Using floating point numbers will not solve your problem because it will round your integer to the closest floating point number and you will lose precision.

"On a typical computer system, a 'double precision' (64-bit) binary floating-point number has a coefficient of 53 bits (one of which is implied), an exponent of 11 bits, and one sign bit." (Wikipedia)

As long as we only deal with powers of 2 then the floating point representation is exact: One significant digit (1) and an exponent equal to 100. So you can get away with using a double. Once you add any number small enough in comparison with the stored number, you are left with the original number as a result. Classic floating point issues.

Comment: They use arrays of ints to implement this, which he said he was not interested in.

Comment: @Segmented Yes, I know but floating points will not do and using a library he will not have to deal with arrays or the like. It's totally transparent.

Comment: I agree, just pointing it out =) This would be my solution too.

Answer (score 1):

You say C++, but this is much easier to do with C I/O (which you can use in C++, but its not really C++).  You just want to print in `f` format with no digits after the decimal:

```
printf("%.0f\n", no);
```

In C++ you can do the same with:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0) << no << std::endl;
```

which is much more verbose, and has persistent effects on later things printed...

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0) << no << std::endl;
```

Complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    double no = 1;
    int i = 1;
    for(i=1;i<=100;i++) no*=2;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0) << no << std::endl;
}
```

Prints:

```
1267650600228229401496703205376
```

(Which is exactly 2^100, but if you do `no + 1.0` in the above code, it prints exactly the same value, since adding one is outside of the covered precision of the value.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an array to simulate it.  It is a good problem to solve as it's is useful for other Euler problems.